# access vagrant from device on local network

Tags: linux, vagrant, vagrantfile

I updates on vagrantfile in device A

```
# Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
# Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
# your network.
config.vm.network :public_network, ip: "192.168.10.121"
```

and then update in /etc/hosts in device B

```
192.168.10.121 test.localhost
```

then I try to access in device B using browser 'test.localhost' but there is no result

Comment: Can you post output of
`tracepath -n 192.168.10.121` from host machine?

Comment: 1:  192.168.10.1                                          0.344ms pmtu 1500
     1:  192.168.10.1                                          2997.331ms !H 
     Resume: pmtu 1500